# garbage value in C array

Tags: c, arrays, linux, gcc

I am trying to write a C code that will print a pyramid structure on screen, something like this.

[image]

The corresponding code I've written is something like this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

void printArrayFunc(char arr[9][5]) {
  int i, j;
  printf("=========================================\nprinting the values\n");
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
      //printf("arr[%d][%d] = %d\n", i,j, arr[i][j]);
      if (arr[i][j] == 1)
        printf("*");
      else
        printf(" ");
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
}


int main() {
  int i, j;
  char arr[9][5] = {
    0
  };

  printf("============================\nfilling the values\n");
  for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    for (j = 4 - i; j <= 4 + i; j++) {
      arr[i][j] = 1;
      // printf("arr[%d][%d]= %d\n",i,j,arr[i][j]);
    }
    //printf("\n");
  }
  printArrayFunc(arr);

  return 0;
}
```

It is giving an output like

[image]

I know I'm doing some silly mistake but at this moment, I'm not able to find what is going wrong. Let me hear your comments on this.

Comment: You cannot be serious, posting a *screenshot* of a text window.

Comment: At least OP posted his code.

Comment: @KerrekSB No other choice, i'm working on virtualbox, and somehow shared folder is not working.

Comment: The problem is in your array indexing. On some of them you have your `i` and `j` switched (trying to access `arr[4][8]` goes outside your array).

Comment: Also, you should avoid doing routine work while logged in as root.  If your program should go wonky, being a non-privileged user prevents damage to the system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the function argument:

```
char arr[9][5]
```

In the loop:

```
for (i = 0; i<5; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j<9;j++) {
        if (arr[i][j] == 1)
```

You flipped the position of `i` and `j`. `i` should go from 0 to 9, `j` from 0 to 5.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (arr[i][j] == 1)
    printf("*");
else 
    printf(" ");
```

This statement is giving the garbage value in this statement if `if condition` is true then it print else statement and when else comes true it prints the garbage value.